# Angular 2 form control without name

Tags: angular, forms

I'm stuck with an Angular 2 form. I want a single point to check if the whole form is valid or not, so I put all controls inside a `<form>` tag. This leads to an error message:

```
Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

  Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
  Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

It is quite clear, and there are already some questions about this on SO. The second example is not an option, because a standalone control is not validated with the whole form. So I definitely need a name.

The problem is: I don't have anything unique that could be used as a name. The form displays a dynamic collection of entities, and their names are to be entered by the user. I tried to use the element's index inside the collection, but as I add or remove elements, this will also change. Angular seems not to be capable of handling changing form element names, as you can see in this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/TtVbaOrrf28X7lv7fKYD/). (Just change the second element, delete the first and add another one - it will produce strange results.)

Is there any way to solve this without validating every form control by hand?

Comment: If I use the same name for multiple form controls, I get strange results (they overwrite each other etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you use a `*ngFor` right ?

If so, you can use a custom trackBy function, and name them after the index. This would give

```html
<div *ngfor="let x of y; let i = index; trackBy: myTrackBy" [name]="'myField_' + i">...</div>
```

In your TS

```js
myTrackBy(index, item) {
  return item.id || index; // try returning the item ID first, otherwise the index
}
```

Comment: I can explain with my own words, but I think a quick google search would help you more. [I've found this article](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5) that explains it correctly, is it enough or should I use my own words ? (disclaimer : this is how I understood it from a "I don't code that often" point of view)

Comment: The article uses `trackBy` as a performance optimization to render only changed items instead of the whole collection. I don't get why that solves the problem. If Angular really renders everything without `trackBy`, that should be enough?

Comment: This is because you're looping over primitive-typed items. ngFor can't keep track of your variables identities because when the value changes from 'John' to 'Johnny',(when you edit) it becomes a new, different identity. you can either use the custom track by function, or write your ngModel as `[(ngModel)]="persons[i]firstName"` (or of course, use objects, since they're not primtives)